# How to generate Avro schemas in Go automatically?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to integrate Avro and Schema Registry in our Kafka data pipelines. Now it looks inside of Go service like

Get data -> Encode data to JSON -> Write to Kafka

I want to use avro schema in the same way

Generate schema -> Update schema in Schema Registry -> Get data -> Encode to Avro -> Write to Kafka

But there are several questions:

1. How can I generate schema from Go classes automatically?
2. How should I check schema compatibility with Schema Registry?

Comment: Have you looked at libraries that do this? For example https://github.com/linkedin/goavro

Comment: Schema Registry has a documented API for compatibility checking

Comment: @JohnGiotta don't they do it the other way around. I mean generating avro schema from go code ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am going to write my own probably as I can't find anything still 4 years later.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternatives to create go classes from Avro. did you try this https://github.com/actgardner/gogen-avro?

> Usage To generate Go source files from one or more Avro schema files,
>   run:
>
> gogen-avro [--package=] [--containers] output_directory avro_schema files

Confluent Schema registry provide several ways to check compatibility betwween schemas. You can take a look to their API [Here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html#id1). There are other ways to do it, for example using maven during your integration tests to ensure compatibility between your source and other enviroments. You can find some information [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/docs/maven-plugin.rst).